# development android app on Android studio and github

Tags: android-studio, github, module, project

My question is simple

We use github on our android app development, Use android studio
between project and module, Which one should we push to github,
the project folder contains many local setting(SDK etc), So i think maybe we can only push the module to github, Am i right?

PLS tell my what you guys does